# PHP to build windows application

Tags: php, windows, gtk

I wanted to know if is it possible to create something like below.

I have a requirement where client need to see total number of stocks on his windows desktop sidebar (gadget). Where user update 2 records in database, and this 2 records should appear in windows desktop sidebar.

If this was web app i was doing it without any issues, but client requires desktop app. So is it possible to build using PHP-GTK? Or is there any other library for php?

Example:

```
+----+------------+
| name   | stock  |
+----+------------+
| name01 |   6    |
| name02 |   4    |
+----+------------+
```

Comment: I dont know why this question is closed, I found that by using app.js or tidesdk.org i can build desktop apps. And one down vote for this question?!! Any ways thank you all of you for anwering..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows desktop gadgets (up to Vista, anyway) can be built using Javascript and HTML only.

If the data you need to be accessed is available on an external web server, you can just make an AJAX call to get them and display them using Javascript.

If you mean it for Windows 8, then you need to build an app, as gadgets are not available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP for anything but "Pretty Home Pages" isn't a very good idea. If i remember correctly PHP-GTK has stopped being supported a while ago. As a matter of fact all you will need is some html and javascript and have some webserver provide you the data you wish to display.

Here is a link to the MSDN article about [Developing a Gadget for Windows Sidebar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb456468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

U can try it with php-gtk, but that would be like reinventing the wheel when you can easily do the same stuff by the use of many other languages like python,java

Answer (score 0):

If this has to be a Windows sidebar widget you don't need to create a stand-alone application. It can be done by as a webpage that would refresh -- let's say -- every 10 seconds to get what has changed.

The other way could be to use RSS feeds. There is also a widget to handle this.